# I have a bug in my code that is giving me weird output for my cost function when I try to get the output

Tags: python, pytorch, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am new to data science industry and have been working on my second project. I am implementing gradient descent to my linear regression to optimize my cost model, but the output from my C variable seemed very strange. Can someone please tell me if I coded this correctly or is there something I am doing wrong? Below is my code:

```
#Model Creation 
import torch 
import random from sklearn.preprocessing 
import StandardScaler

input1 = (MarginMerged.drop(['BTC', 'Date'], 1)) 
input2 = torch.tensor(inputs.astype(float).values) 
output = torch.tensor([MarginMerged['BTC']])

sc=StandardScaler() 
standardized_x = sc.fit_transform(input2) #Standardizing for better convergence of Gradients

w1 = torch.randn(1, requires_grad = True) #Randomizing weights and allowing tracking of gradients 
w2 = torch.randn(1, requires_grad = True) 
w3 = torch.randn(1, requires_grad = True) 
w4 = torch.randn(1, requires_grad = True) 
b = torch.randn(1, requires_grad = True)

def regression(x1, w1, x2, w2, x3, w3, x4, w4, b): #Simple regression 
    function y = x1 * w1 + x2 * w2 + x3 * w3 + x4 * w4 + b return y

#Evaluating Model and Cost Function 
yhat = regression(input2[:, 0], w1, input2[:, 1], w2, input2[:, 2], w3, input2[:, 3], w4, b)

def MSE(yhat, y): 
    sigma = torch.sum((yhat - y) **2) return sigma / len(y)

C = MSE(yhat, output)

Output: 
tensor([  -766136.2741,   -910269.9667,   -827688.1826,   -825344.9633,
          -886781.1021,   -939034.5842,   -999291.1625,   -996561.4835,
         -1355946.4095,  -1101955.2536,  -1142216.8116,  -1212749.9003,
         -1737812.1974,  -1621638.2128,  -1758945.7766,  -2119769.5569,
         -2590650.6940,  -3916453.0230,  -4122350.1070,  -9693393.5401,
        -13584547.6533, -17504209.3513, -24114284.5156, -22302542.7874,
        -19064275.4255, -35323125.1089, -86678884.6189, -66240221.4384,
        -41395859.9706, -34334016.6174, -18819275.6493, -16508314.3713,
         -9682844.7546, -14240738.2622, -11479996.4053,  -9299528.3805,
         -9841421.4224, -15140955.9555, -10965320.5364,  -6465157.0859,
         -6044804.7645,  -4984105.2754,  -7711268.3907, -11424855.3688,
        -12303663.6678, -14704509.5725,  -9483839.7203,  -7645405.3528,
         -5656487.9378,  -5047090.0958,  -3954263.1534,  -5806911.3040,
         -8229332.1597, -12360791.8777, -11092046.1287], dtype=torch.float64,

*Output should be positive due to implementing MSE*
```

Comment: Please make sure your code is formatted correctly. When you say `C` is strange, what do you mean? Is it high? Low? Inconsistent?

Comment: C is a variable, you can see the last line in his code.

Comment: my C variable seemed very strange , could you please post your strange output?

Comment: C should be positive as it is the cost of my MSE function, but its outputting negative values in the millions.

Comment: I added the outputs of C in the edit